# It's possible to make dropdown menus in bootstrap work as accordions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**EDIT**: seems like the newest version of bootstrap (2.2.2) this has already been implemented.

---

As you can see in the image, when the `navbar` is collapsed the menus are expanded, it can be a problem if you have more than 4 or 4 dropdown menus so in small screens it can make the page very long.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

[image]

**So the question is, it's possible to make the dropdowns work as accordions?**

I tried using `data-toggle="collapse"` but then the dropdowns stop working.